# How to deploy spring boot application to GCP cloud functions?

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a Spring Boot Application which we deploy as a lambda function on AWS. Is there a similar way to deploy a Sprint Boot Application as GCP cloud function?

Excuse me if the question is naive but I couldn't find any straight forward way from the GCP documentation.

Comment: Did you every find a way to use GCF for your SpringBoot app?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a way to deploy a Spring Boot application as a GCP cloud function.

As mentioned in [this](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/introducing-java-11-on-google-cloud-functions) article of May 26th, 2020:

> The Google Cloud Java Frameworks team worked with the Spring team to
> bring Spring Cloud GCP project to help Spring Boot users easily
> leverage Google Cloud services. More recently, the team worked with
> the Spring Cloud Function team to bring you Spring Cloud Function GCP
> Adapter. A function can just be a vanilla Java function, so you can
> run a Spring Cloud Function application on Cloud Functions without
> having to modify your code to run on Google Cloud.
>
> ```
> @Bean
> public Function<String, String> uppercase() {
>   return value -> value.toUpperCase();
> }
> ```

Please have a look at [this](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/tree/master/spring-cloud-function-samples/function-sample-gcp-http) GitHub repository as it contains the full example.

Comment: YOu can use Spring Boot framework in function but you need to change your current code. Not sure that is the expected solution.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you to have a look to [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs). If your Spring Boot app already start in standalone (with spring boot starter), the Cloud Run packaging is easy. You can find example in [my repo](https://github.com/guillaumeblaquiere/cloudrun-java-framework/tree/master/springboot), or [through this article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/java-frameworks-performances-on-cloud-run-eb243fd84a5c) (and others)

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Would definitely give it a shot

Comment: @guillaume-blaquiere Does it have to be Cloud Run or is there a way to do it via GCF as well? I'm in the same boat as OP where my company wants to go from AWS Lambda to GCF

Comment: You can use Spring Cloud Functions, but I don't like it. too heavy and you can't manage the HTTP return status as you wish; Definitively, CLoud Run is the best! https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-function

Answer (score 1):

Most places I've worked will build/compile a fat-jar of their spring-boot application, drop it in to a docker container (create a Dockerfile and then build the image), then deploy the container 1 or many times over using the image as a basis (and have a load balancer in front of it for the many instances set up).

Today we have kubernetes/ansible, etc. Pick your poison or go without.. it's what will work best for you, but these technologies can be a hinderance or a help depending on the size of your operation.

Comment: I am looking for a serverless architecture. The approach suggested by you isn't a serverless architecture.

Comment: You may want to learn more about serverless as this is serverless https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/ - architecture as code means you can use Kubernetes or whatever tool suits you best to deploy docker images to pods running containers... docker images are the current standard way to package applications for serverless architecture. Docker containers tend to run Fat Jars in the java world.

Answer (score 0):

To deploy my Spring Boot application on Google App Engine, I did the following:

Added the following maven plugin:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <version>1</version>
          <projectId>levelupfin-1fe89</projectId>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Created the following file: src/main/appengine/app.yaml

```
runtime: java11
instance_class: F1
```

Ran the following commands:

```
# To deploy to app engine
mvn appengine:deploy
# To see your app
gcloud app browse
```

I got much of this info from the following [code lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-app-engine-springboot#0).