# How to run my spring boot application into a cloud function environment?

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-functions

It's been a long time since I have asked a question.
I am currently working on a small project in order to learn how to use Google Cloud.
I have built a simple application that draw some numbers and return them to the client.

This is a Spring Boot application that connect to a google cloud SQL.
As a standalone application, my application runs pretty well and can do the job needed.

I can't happen to run my application in a cloud function Environment.
I believe it is what I need since I don't care about the infrastructure.

Here are the class that I have :

CheckerApplication.java

```
package fr.checker;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "fr.checker.infrastructure.repository")
public class CheckerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CheckerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Here is my pom.xml where I feel that the modification as to be done :
pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>fr.checker</groupId>
    <artifactId>checker</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>checker</name>
    <description>Pulling random number</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>20</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.4</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- GOOGLE CLOUD DEPENDENCY -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud.sql/postgres-socket-factory -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgres-socket-factory</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

DrawingController.java

```
package fr.checker.presentation.controller;

import fr.checker.application.service.DrawingService;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class DrawingController {

    private final DrawingService drawingService;

    public DrawingController(DrawingService drawingService) {
        this.drawingService = drawingService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/draw")
    public String drawMyNumbers(@RequestParam(required = false, name = "tolerance") Integer tolerance) {
        if(tolerance == null || tolerance == 0)
            return drawingService.drawNumbers().toString();
        return drawingService.drawNumbersSpecifically(tolerance).toString();
    }

}
```

DrawingFunction.java

```
package fr.checker.presentation.function;

import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpFunction;
import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpRequest;
import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class DrawingFunction implements HttpFunction {

    @Autowired
    DrawingController drawingController;

    @Override
    public void service(HttpRequest httpRequest, HttpResponse httpResponse) throws Exception {
        httpResponse.setStatusCode(200);
        httpResponse.getWriter().write(drawingController.drawMyNumbers(50));
    }

}
```

MANIFEST.MF

```
Main-Class: fr.checker.presentation.function.DrawingFunction
```

As you can guess I feel I am mixing everything since I need to use spring IoC in order to have my Function working.

Do you have any suggestions on the part of the code to look at to make it runnable as a cloud function ?

Please note that I have already check this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63700087/how-to-deploy-spring-boot-application-to-gcp-cloud-functions).

Please note that this application works well in a standalone mode.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what difficulty you're having.

Comment: I recommend looking into Google Cloud Run and not Cloud Functions. IMHO, Spring Boot will often work well as a serverless containerized application but not as a Function. I view Cloud Run as Cloud Function's big brother. Note: Function v2 runs on Cloud Run [reference](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/version-comparison#new-in-2nd-gen).

Comment: @JohnHanley : Will look Look into Cloud Run but I feel this is more configuration while I just want to be code focused.